# Selenium webdriver - TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I've gone through every one of the suggested searches on here. I've downloaded ***geckodriver*** and threw it in my "path". I actually threw it in the folder where python is installed and i used `os.path.dirname(sys.executable)` to see where `python` was currently pulling from/looking at and threw it in there as well.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.sosnc.gov/online_services/search/by_title/_Business_Registration_changes')
search_button = driver.find_element_by_id('search')
```

Comment: just change firefox to Firefox

Comment: I tried that as well.  Just to make sure, it just tried it again and it didn't work. :( I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: what was the error this time?

Comment: Got the same error

Comment: Share your full code

Comment: ok, i just noticed that when it returns the error, it shows driver = webdriver.firefox() regardless if it's "Firefox" or "firefox" in my script. does that make sense?

Comment: that is the code i have.  I'm a total newbie at this and i run it every few lines to make sure no errors pop up before moving on to the next few lines.

Comment: I think the code you are sharing and the code you are running is different.And second it should be webdriver.Firefox() instead of webdriver.firefox()

Comment: i just double checked, even took out the #comment and updated the code. It's the same. i don't have any other code to go with it.

Comment: ok, try removing the path that you added you mentioned and then tell me the error

Comment: i really apologize, but i'm confused.  In my post, i referred to adding geckodriver to my path.  But that's it.

Comment: yes try removing that geckodriver from the path and then tell me the error

Comment: same exact error.  that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be an issue with my computer. Not sure why, but when i ran the script on a different computer, it ran fine. thanks for the help.